# Selecting the next row in a mysql subselect

Tags: mysql, select, row-number

I've got a table of data thats ordered by a non-primary key e.g.

```
id |   likes
4  |     6  
2  |     5
5  |     2
3  |     2
1  |     2
```

I need a query to find the row after id #5 which would be id #3.

I've tried using row numbers and written this but it seems really inefficient

```
select * from (
                SELECT  l.id,
                l.likes,
                @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
                FROM    sk_posters l
                JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                WHERE active = 'yes'
                order by likes desc, id desc)
            as mycount where row_number =
            (select row_number from (
                SELECT  l.id,
                l.likes,
                @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
                FROM    sk_posters l
                JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                WHERE active = 'yes'
                order by likes desc, id desc)
            as mycount
            where id=5)+1 limit 1
```

If there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: your table and query not matching. Can u provide some sample data in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit at the end of query like

```
  SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE LIMIT 2,1
```